# Trying to render a JSX component inside TSX makes TS interpret the JSX component's arguments as string

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm migrating certain parts of the codebase to `TS` and I have an original `JSX` component `Icon` that's defined as follows:

```js
export const Icon = ({ width, height}) => {
  return(<div></div>);
};
```

Inside my `Dropdown.tsx`, I'm using it as such:

```
import { Icon } from './Icon';

type Props = {
  id: string,
  props?: object
}

export const Dropdown = ({id, ...props}: Props): JSX.Element => {
  return <Icon />;
}
```

However, TS screams at me with `TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'.` when I'm trying to render `Icon`. I can get it to render if I just do `Icon('')` which solves the issue TS is telling me about, but, obviously, I can't pass any arguments to the component. Why can't a `TSX` component work with a `JSX` component?

The code, as I provided it, should work: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-matan-igjrp?file=/src/Dropdown.tsx - it's just something on my end that I can't figure out.

---

Here's my setup:

webpack.js:

```
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        exclude: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ]
    }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",

    "strict": true,

    "sourceMap": true,

    "moduleResolution": "node",

    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,

    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,

    "target": "ESnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "declaration": true,

    "jsx": "react",

    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules"
      }
    ]
  },
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "REDACTED": ["src/index.js"]
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["./out.d.ts", "node_modules", "dist", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.jsx"]
}
```

Comment: Where are all TS types? You didn't typed the Icon as React component React.FC<Props>

Comment: Seems to work https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUI1gB6Sxy4QB2q8Akl25wAvHAAUAbzgB3YABMYACwA0cJVmABzJTAC+cAFxxpcxUoD8x7gFcQAIyxQ1G7bqtxbDp3oCUogD4TRjg4ShgbKG5xAB55YAA3AJiAenik33oGPSzGGABPMCw4AAViMHQxSRC4BWM+KGBuLRUasHLUDwh7ACssfEY9RmY2aHghPjgAEXL5CBlhMSkFNQA6dfaICr1jMq3UX2MAKQBlAA1VgFEAGywQLG54ESDqhlDwyOEYwR44FICsnogA

Comment: @DennisVash It's intended. I know that I can just transform the `jsx` component to as `tsx` one and call it a day, but I thought TS would have no issue working with files this way.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Aye, I was told this shouldn't be a problem. It's just something with my setup that messes it up, which is why I asked here. I've tried messing around with all settings, but no success.